# How to check if record already exists in SQLite table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is my `database`

```
public void DBCreate() {
    SQLITEDATABASE = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("FavoritesDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    SQLITEDATABASE.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS favorite(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, word VARCHAR, meaning VARCHAR);");
}
```

This is how I am creating new rows:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO favorite (word,meaning) VALUES('"+wordd+"', '"+mean+"');";
Cursor c=SQLITEDATABASE.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM favorite WHERE id=?", null);
if (c.moveToFirst())
{      
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    SQLITEDATABASE.execSQL(query);
}
else
{
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

How to check data before inserting value into table?

Answer (score 1):

before inserting perform select query and check the `cursor` size if it is >0 than record already exist .

I am not sure why are you passing `null` in your query

```
 Cursor c=SQLITEDATABASE.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM favorite WHERE id=?", null);
```

instead

```
Cursor c=SQLITEDATABASE.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM favorite WHERE id=?", new String[]{"your id1"});
```

or 
if you want to select all record then

```
Cursor c=SQLITEDATABASE.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM favorite");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    Cursor c = SQLITEDATABASE.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM favorite WHERE id=?", new String[]{"your_id_name"});
    Log("Cursor Count : " + c.getCount());
               if(c.getCount()>0)
                {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else
                {
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   SQLITEDATABASE.execSQL(query);
                }
```

And your select query should look like:

```
String sql ="SELECT PID FROM "+TableName+" WHERE PID="+pidValue;
```

Comment: `public void DBCreate(int pidValue)`

Comment: pidValue is the particular value  that you check in a row...if it is already inserted..

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. If you do not want to repeat any of the values in a column, set the column setting in the CREATE method to "UNIQUE" or even "PRIMARY KEY" if the content should be the primary key to recognize. Thus you can probably avoid any repetitions without having to check.
2. Loop through the table:

   ```
    Cursor c = SQLITEDATABASE.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM favorite", null);

    if (c.getCount() > 0) {

        String searchString = "some word"; // word you are about to insert

        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            c.moveToFirst();
            int colIndex = c.getColumnIndex("word");
            String wordInCurrentRow = c.getString(colIndex);

            if (!(wordInCurrentRow.equals(searchString))) {
                // insert method
            } else {
                // do nothing
                Log.d("word already existing", "nothing to insert");
            }
        }
    }
   ```